# Java: Converting between Key type and String

Tags: java, rsa, public-key-encryption

Is it possible to take a public key that I have generated, convert it into a string, reverse the process and use it as a key again?

```
    generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    generator.initialize(2048);

    KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();

    RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
    RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
```

Then convert this to a string:

```
String public = someMethod(publicKey)
```

and then Reverse it at a later time:

```
RSAPublicKey newPublicKey = someMethod(public)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the Public Key to a String as follows.

```
String publicKeyString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded());
```

Then that String can be converted back to a public key as follows.

```
byte[] publicKeyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyString);
X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey publicKey2 = keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);
```

Comment: Surely the base64-decoder accepts a `String` argument?